# Change Color Text with If-Else statements in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So basically, this is my code:

```
#Imports Tk gui syntax
from Tkinter import *

#Creates App class
class App(Tk):

    #Initiates class
    def __init__(self):

        #Initiates Tk
        Tk.__init__(self)

        #Creates title of app
        self.title("BMI Calculator")

        #adds extra line for a cleaner gui
        self.fillerLine = Label(self, text = "")
        self.fillerLine.grid(row=0, column=0)

        #asks user for height
        self.hgtOutput = Label(self, text = "What is your height (in inches)? :")
        self.hgtOutput.grid(row=1, column=0)

        #user inputs height in inches using a slider
        self.hgtInput = Scale(self, from_=0, to=96, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=450)
        self.hgtInput.pack()
        self.hgtInput.grid(row=1, column=1)

        #button asking user to confirm height
        self.btnConfirmHGT = Button(self, text = "Confirm Your Hegiht", command = self.confirmHGT)
        self.btnConfirmHGT.grid(row=3, column=0)

        #prints the height the user input in feet and inches
        self.printHGT = Label(self, text = "\n\n")
        self.printHGT.grid(row=3, column=1)

        #extra line for cleaner gui
        self.fillerLine = Label(self, text = "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        self.fillerLine.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

        #asks user for weight in pounds
        self.wghtOutput = Label(self, text = "What is your weight (in pounds)? :")
        self.wghtOutput.grid(row=5, column=0)

        #user inputs weight using a slider
        self.wghtInput = Scale(self, from_=0, to=400, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=450)
        self.wghtInput.pack()
        self.wghtInput.grid(row=5, column=1)

        #button to start calculations
        self.btnCalc = Button(self, text = "Calculate", command = self.calculate)
        self.btnCalc.grid(row=6, columnspan=2)

        #extra line for cleaner gui
        self.fillerLine = Label(self, text = "---------------------------------------------")
        self.fillerLine.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2)

        #prints users BMI
        self.tellBMI = Label(self, text = "")
        self.tellBMI.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=2)

        #prints what category the user is in, underweight, normal, overweight, obese
        self.catBMI = Label(self, text = "")
        self.catBMI.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=2)

        #extra line for cleaner gui
        self.fillerLine = Label(self, text = "---------------------------------------------")
        self.fillerLine.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.mainloop()

    #function to make sure the user put in the correct height
    def confirmHGT(self):
        feet = (self.hgtInput.get())/12
        inches = (self.hgtInput.get())%12
        #print the height the user input
        self.printHGT["text"] = "\nYou're height is : %s ft. & %s in. \n" % (feet, inches)

    #function that calculates BMI and places it within a category
    def calculate(self):
        #Formula calculating BMI using the height and weight given by the user
        BMI = ((self.wghtInput.get()/float(self.hgtInput.get() ** 2))*703)
        #Prints users BMI
        self.tellBMI["text"] = "You're BMI is:\n %2.1f\n" % (BMI)
        #
        if BMI < 18.5:
            self.catBMI["text"] = "Grab a cheeseburger! You are underweight."
        elif BMI >= 18.5 and BMI <= 24.9:
             self.catBMI["text"] = "Congratulations! You are normal!"
        elif BMI >= 25.0 and BMI <= 29.9:
             self.catBMI["text"] = "Maybe eat some salad! You are overweight."
        elif BMI >= 30.0:
             self.catBMI["text"] = "Hit the treadmills! You are obese."
        else:
             pass

#creates an instance of the App() class
def main():
    a = App()

#runs main() function
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The code runs perfectly fine for what I want to do, I'm just trying to make some minor improvements to learn. What I'm trying to do is, if BMI is in the underweight category, give the "Grab a cheeseburger! You are underweight." statement a yellow background. If in the normal category, give the "Congratulations! You are normal!" statement a green background. If in the overweight category, a yellow background, and the obese category a red background. All with keeping the normal background until the calculate button is pressed.

I tried the,

```
tag_add()
tag_config()
```

but I can't seem to figure it out, and don't know where to go next!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just set the `background` property when you change the text property:

```
if BMI < 18.5:
    self.catBMI["text"] = "Grab a cheeseburger! You are underweight."
    self.catBMI["background"] = "yellow"
elif BMI >= 18.5 and BMI <= 24.9:
    self.catBMI["text"] = "Congratulations! You are normal!"
    self.catBMI["background"] = "green"
elif BMI >= 25.0 and BMI <= 29.9:
    self.catBMI["text"] = "Maybe eat some salad! You are overweight."
    self.catBMI["background"] = "orange"
elif BMI >= 30.0:
    self.catBMI["text"] = "Hit the treadmills! You are obese."
    self.catBMI["background"] = "red"
else:
    pass
```

Btw. I don’t think you should call the `self.mainloop` inside the `__init__` method. Doing so will prevent it from ever leaving that method, and that doesn’t seem to be right. Instead, call the `mainloop` after initializing the app:

```
def main():
    a = App()
    a.mainloop()
```

As a futher note, your if/else structure is doing more checks than necessary. If you first check if `BMI < 18.5` and that is *not* the case, then it is automatically true that `BMI >= 18.5`. So you can leave out all the first checks of the `elif`s because they are automatically true since the previous cases were not true. Similarly, the `else` block is never executed. So it’s all just this:

```
if BMI < 18.5:
    self.catBMI["text"] = "Grab a cheeseburger! You are underweight."
    self.catBMI["background"] = "yellow"
elif BMI <= 24.9:
    self.catBMI["text"] = "Congratulations! You are normal!"
    self.catBMI["background"] = "green"
elif BMI <= 29.9:
    self.catBMI["text"] = "Maybe eat some salad! You are overweight."
    self.catBMI["background"] = "orange"
else:
    self.catBMI["text"] = "Hit the treadmills! You are obese."
    self.catBMI["background"] = "red"
```